# ng-file-upload not display window after dialog box in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dialog, angular-material, ng-file-upload

I want to select the files using file-selector after getting confirmation from the user through dialog box. I have used below code to make it work.

```
angular.element('#ngFileElementId').trigger('click');
```

It's working fine in firefox i.e. displaying file-selector using which user can select multiple files after providing confirmation through dialog box but it's not working in chrome.

I think, it is probably a setting error in Chrome which is affecting the working of ng-file-upload.

[CodePen Issue Generator](http://codepen.io/ajaykumarelucidataio/pen/MbeVYx)

Thanks for Reading it.

Regards

Ajay